# How can I set the radio buttons/checkbox already ticked by getting boolean values from a JSON file in a Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, checkbox, radio-button

I'm creating a table with radio buttons and checkboxes that uses data from a JSON within the script. I am able to call other data from the JSON by using:
`${data[i].firstName}`
However, I have no clue on how to call a boolean
value like this and set it on a check list /radio button:
`'gender':{'male':true,'female':false,}`

I want to be able to set the radio buttons and check-list as already check/ticked and locked when the page loads.
This is the line of code that I'm having difficulties to put the JSON values (the radio buttons and checklist):

```
 <td><input type="radio" name="rank"> Male 
     <input type="radio" name="rank"> Female 
 </td>

 <td>
     <input type="checkbox" id="eng">
     <label for="lang1"> English</label>
     <input type="checkbox">
     <label for="lang2"> Japanese</label>
     <input type="checkbox">
     <label for="lang3"> Chinese</label>
 </td>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <tr  class="bg-info">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Birthday</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Known Language</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="myTable">
```

**Javascript:**

```
var myArray = [
        {
        'id':"1",
        'firstName':'John', 
        'lastName':'Doe', 
        'birthday':'1990-05-07',
        'gender':{
          'male':true,
          'female':false,
        },
        'knownLanguage':[
          "English",
          "Japanese",
          "Chinese"
          ]
      },

        {
        'id':"2",
        'firstName':'Lina', 
        'lastName':'Art', 
        'birthday':'1994-08-05',
        'gender':{
          'male':false,
          'female':true,
        },
        'knownLanguage':[
          "English",
          "Japanese"
          ]
      },
    ]
    
buildTable(myArray)

    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
    
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = 
      
            `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].id}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].firstName}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].lastName}</td>
              <td>${data[i].birthday}</td>
              <td><input type="radio" name="rank"> Male 
                  <input type="radio" name="rank"> Female 
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="eng">
                  <label for="lang1"> English</label>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <label for="lang2"> Japanese</label>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <label for="lang3"> Chinese</label>
              </td>
                      </tr>`
       
            table.innerHTML += row


        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally set the 'checked' attribute based on the gender.

In your buildTable function:

(Updated for checkboxes)

```
<td>
  <input type="radio" name="rank" ${data[i].gender.male ? 'checked' : ''}> Male 
  <input type="radio" name="rank" ${data[i].gender.female ? 'checked' : ''}> Female 
</td>

 <td>
     <input type="checkbox" id="eng" ${data[i].knownLanguage.includes('English') ? 'checked' : ''}>
     <label for="lang1"> English</label>
     <input type="checkbox" ${data[i].knownLanguage.includes('Japanese') ? 'checked' : ''}>
     <label for="lang2"> Japanese</label>
     <input type="checkbox" ${data[i].knownLanguage.includes('Chinese') ? 'checked' : ''}>
     <label for="lang3"> Chinese</label>
 </td>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for the radio button, however for the check box since it has no boolean values I wasn't able to make it work and pre select a language. I did however change the known language data to have boolean values and made it work as well.

Comment: I added some extra code for the checkboxes.